ClassNotFoundException is thrown in Unit Tests
I've updated gradle build tool from 8.2.0 to 8.6.1 and getting a lot of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when run unit tests in release
gradle app:testStagingDebugUnitTest

using junit5 vintage engine
/ Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'

//junit5 jupiter
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.11.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.11.2'

any fast solution here ? should I keep this particular class in proguard?
